# What is this Uniform and Medal Ribbon?

Tags: military, uniform

I am trying to help someone.  She has sent me a black & white photo.  I think the battle dress is post WW2? And the man could be an officer? Ie the wearing of a tie.  I just cannot work out the medal ribbon because of it being black and white also there seems to be a metal rosette attached to the medal. [image: headshot of a man in uniform]

Comment: Giter, the photograph was found in a house in Liverpool UK after an old lady passed away. The lady I am helping is also from Liverpool. The old lady never married but had a child a boy but he was taken away from her.  She was originally from London and had to leave and move to Liverpool

Comment: I now believe the medal the Africa Star with the number 8.  The medal was issued during service whilst the remainder of WW2 medals were issued after the war?